# Don't display the Image Fetch From URL online Android

Tags: android

I want to show an image from online (url) but it shows me nothing and i don't know why this happens. I add INTERNET permission in manifest also.

```
    private ImageView iv;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String address = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3_EM3_dBstc/UxD7U2EEa2I/AAAAAAAACmI/M9JilH6eIV0/s100/Krita-logo.png";

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        bitmap = bitImageRead(address);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Where i do wrong?

Comment: show me your code of method bitImageRead(address);

Comment: I import two class for that-    
    1. import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    2. import android.graphics.BitmapFactory

Comment: i am asking for method bitImageRead that is returning some bitmap i think...

Comment: Bro what's the code of bitImageRead(address)

Comment: I don't have any other class for this method.

Comment: Here it is- <br/>
public Bitmap bitImageRead(String src){
     try{
      URL url = new URL(src);
         HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 
         InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
         Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
         return img;
     }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
     }
    }`

Comment: @RohitGoswami , I give the code of that method.

Comment: You will have a `NetworkOnMainThreadExeption`. See the logcat. Put network code in an AsyncTask or thread.

Comment: @greenapps You are right.

Comment: @greenapps Is there any way to get rid from it? I have not any knowledge of it. If not then please help to via providing thread code.

Comment: Well google for it on this site. Or read a lot of pages here. You will soon find code. You need only a few lines. Code looks like new Thread (new Runnable(){run(){bitImageRead();}}).start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
public Bitmap bitImageRead(address){
 try {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: you missed these two lines...  connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();

Comment: OK i am now trying and after a successful result i will reply you.

Comment: Don't forget to run this code in the background thread, or it won't work.